# If a human body were to break down into simple gasses of its component elements as a means of shapeshifting how much solid matter would be left?

Tags: internal-consistency, chemistry, anatomy, biochemistry, shapeshifters

The setting I am working with has several individuals with shapeshifting powers. To deal with the inevitable “shapeshifters seem to violate conservation of mass while shapeshifting” issue, the rules of the setting are such that shapeshifters can seemingly gain excess mass from nowhere (they cannot but it appears that way from the characters’ limited perspective), but they **cannot get rid of it in the same way**. Instead **they get rid of excess mass when they shift by having the excess mass slough off, break down supernaturally fast into simple gaseous compounds of their component elements, and disperse into the atmosphere.**

The shapeshifting process is **relatively hard magic**, interacting with regular physics in a consistent, documentable manner. Having the excess mass evaporate away in gaseous form (even if the reverse isn’t true) makes it seem to the reader like the magic is at least “doing business” with conventional physics, similar to how *The Dresden Files* solves the shapeshifting problem with ectoplasm or *Animorphs* does with Z-space.

The four most common elements of the human body (making up 96.2% of the body by mass, though not molarity), carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, and nitrogen, can all form common atmospheric gasses (methane, carbon dioxide, O<sub>2</sub>, N<sub>2</sub>, water vapor) and be lost that way. However, it seems as though several elements cannot be easily lost in gaseous form (calcium in excess bone matter is the primary offender) and would likely be left behind as solid residue or waste products neither turned into gas nor part of the shapeshifter’s new form.

Several elements would also have to be bound up in larger compounds to avoid being highly reactive or toxic (e.g., calcium as CaCO<sub>2</sub>), so it is not a simple manner of figuring out what percentage of the human body is not made of CHON by mass. Calcium phosphate/calcium sulfate is one way I thought of maybe getting rid of calcium, phosphorus, and sulfur, but I am not sure if there are better/more efficient compounds available.

**I am interested in figuring out how much solid waste matter would be left behind in this shapeshifting process, and what kind of compounds would it form assuming the end products are relatively stable and non-toxic.** For example, the characters come across a white paste, subsequent analysis finds the paste to be high in calcium, potassium, chlorine, and magnesium, and based on this the characters are able to go “yep, we’re in shapeshifter country”. The best way I thought to address this question is to figure out **how much waste matter would be left over if as much of the human body as possible was transmuted into simple gaseous compounds** of its respective materials and then rescale it for however much excess mass is being lost in the shapeshifters.

**Additional Parameters:**

- **As little mass as possible is left behind** - Ideally no mass left behind if at all possible, I can work with that (and actually would prefer it), but I am trying to minimize the amount of excess waste matter that is left behind in a solid form. **I am trying to minimize the amount of solid waste matter produced in the process to reduce the chances of shapeshifter residue being highly noticeable**. The shapeshifters try to hide it through their own actions but I am trying to avoid results that are so obvious that it is impossible to ignore. Avoiding extremely exotic compounds is also encouraged for the same reasons.
- **Assume the composition of the shapeshifters' body is identical to the human body and they have the same physiological needs as humans**. So “their shifting produces compounds that would be toxic to humans but their non-human physiology tolerates it” doesn’t work.
- **More or less room temperature conditions, or at least conditions encounterable in everyday life** - This is mostly because I don’t want the shapeshifters to get cooked by their own bodies as they shift. Plus some compounds may be gaseous at states of 400+ °C but they will condense quickly as they lose heat. **Water vapor gets a bit of a pass** because steam is something that is not inherently lethal and excess water condensation isn’t really noticeable, other compounds that fit the same parameters are okay. Ways of doing it without producing significant amounts of hot water vapor that could scald someone are encouraged.
- **No toxic and/or highly combustible products** - Some components of the human body can be broken down into toxic or highly reactive substances. Like potassium metal (of which approximately 120g can be produced from the average human body), which reacts violently and exothermically when it comes in contact with water, or hydrogen cyanide, which is…hydrogen cyanide. I’d like to avoid these compounds for the simple virtue of not having the shapeshifters burst into flames or poison themselves when they try to shift. Hydrogen gas might get a pass because while highly flammable it won’t burn without a spark, nevertheless I’d like to avoid it if possible.
- **Input and output energy of the reaction is explicitly compensated for by the magic** - The former because if there wasn't some supernatural means of causing compounds to be altered there couldn't be any rapid shape-shifting in any given setting period, and the latter because the act of breaking down a lot of organic tissues into simpler compounds would release a lot of energy (given this is basically what digestion is on a shorter timescale) and again, it would be bad if shapeshifters burst into flames whenever they shifted.
- **New compounds can be formed as needed without regards for things like activation energy but atoms cannot be changed into different elements** - So it is not possible to simply atomically transmute all the calcium atoms into hydrogen ones and call it a day.

EDIT: Significantly revised the question to make it clearer what I am asking, what the parameters are and why, and what rules are allowed to be bent within the fictional setting.

Comment: Matter in a gaseous state is not 'lost'. Nothing about your question makes sense, scientifically.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat 'Lost' as in 'removed from the object to dissipate into the atmosphere', not 'violating the conservation of matter'. In the same way that boiling a pot of water eventually leaves it empty because the water evaporates into water vapor. The atoms aren't 'lost' because they miraculously disappear, they're lost because they disperse into the air and are outside the pot.

Comment: Sulphur is not a gas at room temperature. While it's true that it can form sulphur dioxide, in doing so it prevents the formation of an equivalent amount of carbon dioxide. So it's probably best to leave either carbon or sulphur out of the list.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast lots of other gas-phase carbon bearing oxygen-free wossnames, though. Methane, for one. Hydrogen cyanide for another, if it were warm enough. Even sulphur can form hydrogen sulphide, and there are gaseous thiols like methanethiol that have a carbon, too.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it. You say that carbon is converted into gaseous carbon dioxide: where does the oxygen come from? Are we allowed to bring extra atoms from outside the body? (And water is a liquid under normal conditions, not a gas.)

Comment: @AlexP presumably some could come from the water, of which there will be quite a lot.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: Proteins, fats and sugars need external energy (and lots of it) to react with water. If we are simply allowed to handwave moving component atoms between molecules with no regard of energy, we are left with excess hydrogen, which we can handwave into forming calcium monohydride with the calcium in the bones and voilà everything is a gas!

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question because it is not clear how this question is off-topic or not about worldbuilding. I am asking how much matter would be left behind if something like a death ray that turned flesh into CO2 and H2O was used without violating conservation of matter. This is a question that relates to worldbuilding the processes of a setting and cannot be asked on other communities (e.g., Chemistry Stack Exchange) because it inherently bends some rules of physics to work (i.e., no mass release of energy) due to its science-fiction context.

Comment: @AlexP The human body is 18% carbon, 10% hydrogen, and 65% oxygen, lots of oxygen to spare. Water is a liquid at room temperature, but there is water vapor in the air and the water can always evaporate as steam, even if it will condense back out into liquid water later. Calcium monohydride is highly reactive with water though, which would violate the "not highly reactive" part.

Comment: Ugh, there is not at all lots of oxygen to spare. You must count by number of atoms (or moles), not by weight. An oxygen atom is 16 times as heavy as a hydrogen atom.

Comment: @AlexP In that case getting rid of it as methane would probably be easier. Looking it up the human body has 2700 moles of oxygen and 1300 of carbon, you would need 10600 moles of hydrogen to turn all of that into water vapor and methane. The human body only has 6900 moles of hydrogen. Which means you would have some oxygen, carbon, or both, left over depending on how you split things.

Comment: If you say, "Magic", then **NOTHING** might remain. Even heavy metals or calcium ions can be made volatile; it might take a complex organic molecule (to the tune of *1,1,1,2,2,3,3,7,7,8,8,9,9,9‐tetradecafluorononane‐4,6‐dione* maybe) but they will go up in the air. And since most of the human body is made up of *oxygen* and *hydrogen* as well as carbon, there's no scarcity of materials to build complex organic molecules. The problem is energy and reaction equilibria, and *magic* will take care of that. The body goes not with a bang, but a whi_s_per.

Answer (score 4):

**Cremation does what you propose.**

https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2006/07/i-m-burning-up-how-much-will-my-ashes-weigh.html

This estimates 3-5 pounds of ash after cremation. Volatiles leave and carbon leaves as CO2. The ash will mostly be calcium salts and oxides from the bone.  Sodium and potassium salts will be present too since that is a major component of organic ash generally and we contain a fair bit of those.  There will be traces of metals since those are in the body too; mostly iron and small amounts of the others.

Comment: In addition to trace amounts of heavy metals if any consumption of them had occured in the individuals life time.   Humans cannot excrete heavy metals as waste products, so they remain in the system forever.

Comment: @hszmv That is not true. An acute lead intoxication is usually down to normal after ten years or so. Most other metals are also purged over time, unless fixed in bone tissue or similar. Of course a permanent damage might remain, or you might not survive that long.

Comment: @hxzmv Also, [lead toxicity](https://www.uspharmacist.com/article/lead-toxicity) kicks in around 50 ug / dL.  The average adult has 5 L of blood volume, so that's ~2.5g of Pb.  Even in very acute cases you wouldn't notice this extra mass vs. the variation within a population